# How to show data after validation?

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, post, controller

I have a registration form:

**regStore.jsp**

```
<form:form id = "storeRegForm" method="POST" action="/regStoreSuccessful" commandName="storeForm">
<h3>Registration store</h3>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td><form:label path="name">Store name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    <td><form:errors path="name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form:label path="storeType.id">Store type</form:label></td>
    <td><form:select path="storeType.id" >
      <form:options items="${typeList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
    </form:select></td>
    <td><form:errors path="storeType.id" /></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form:label path="address">Store address</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
    <td><form:errors path="address" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And also have in my controller two methods(GET, POST):

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/regStore", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addStore() throws SQLException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Store/regStore");

    modelAndView.addObject("storeForm", new Store());
    modelAndView.addObject("typeList", storeTypeService.getAllTypes());
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/regStoreSuccessful", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addStorePost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("storeForm") Store storeForm, BindingResult bindingResult) throws SQLException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:body");

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        modelAndView.addObject("storeForm", storeForm);
        modelAndView.addObject("typeList", storeTypeService.getAllTypes());
        return new ModelAndView("Store/regStore");
    }

    storeService.addStore(storeForm);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

In my model, **annotation, like this**:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "Name of store can't be empty")
private String name;
```

And additionally **Client side validation:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".registration #storeRegForm").validate({
  rules: {
    name: "required",
    address : "required"
  },
  messages: {
    name: "Name isn't be null",
    address : "Address isn't be null"
  }
});
});
</script>
```

If I comment out code validation with jQuery(client side validation), and my form field will be is empty, begin work server side validation, but after server side validation, in form not show a list of the types of store, more shown in image:

[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is very simple, in your `if` block you fill-in data to predefined modelAndView but then return different instance!

```
if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    modelAndView.addObject("storeForm", storeForm);
    modelAndView.addObject("typeList", storeTypeService.getAllTypes());
    // !!!!!!
    return new ModelAndView("Store/regStore");
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's work, my finally solution:
            ModelAndView modelAndView1 = new ModelAndView("Store/regStore");
            modelAndView1.addObject("storeForm", storeForm);
            modelAndView1.addObject("typeList", storeTypeService.getAllTypes());
            return modelAndView1;
        }